# Setting background color for <html> element (without height set to 100%) apply to the whole viewport

Tags: html, css

I found setting background color for entire `<html>` element  (without height set to 100%) result in the whole viewport was set to that color

This html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
  html {
    background-color: green;
    border: 5px dashed white;
    margin : 20px
  }

  body {
    background-color: wheat;
    border: 5px dashed red;
    margin : 20px

  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>  
    1
    <br>
    2
    <br>
    3 
</body>

</html>
```

will result like this

[image]

Obviously, the height of html element is less than the height of viewport, why the background color could extend to whole viewport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [the spec says so](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background):

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the
> canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for
> 'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was
> painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not
> paint this background again.

Comment: I tried `html{margin:20px; border:1px solid #000;} body{margin:20px;background:yellow; border: 1px solid #000;}` Spill happened and html, viewport all just got painted by yellow. Is this the intended behavior? There should be gap in backgrounds of `viewport` and `html` area - they should be white? Don't you think?

Comment: @Deadpool — Now you're asking about what happens when you set the background on the body element, which is a different question. Look at the paragraph I quoted from the spec. Then read the next paragraph.

Comment: I know what happens, spill will happen. The question is on implementation in browser. I find this wrong and inconsistant. What do you think?

Comment: @Deadpool — I think you should read the part of the specification I pointed you at in my previous comment which explicitly says that is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's just the browser trying to match colours with the HTMLs background to better blend in. I think it might look weird especially back in the days where most stuff was sized via pixel values.

Extending a browser page wouldn't result in a rough cut of colour where it changes to white or something. But I would guess that's a browserspecific implementation but don't quote me on that.